# Folium map fit to screen, when scrolled zooms too much

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to fit the US map to screen using Folium. when scrolled through the map it will zoom in and zoom out too much which is not clearly visible. I need to fit the map to screen to view it.
The issue is for parameter zoom_start=5 I'm getting below map[image: for zoom_start=5]

for zoom_start=4, I'm getting zoomed out map like this[image: zoom_start=4]

I need to fit the map correctly so that I can see the state names properly.
Here is my sample code:

```
from folium.features import DivIcon
import folium
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import folium, os

ky_counties = gpd.read_file('cb_2021_us_county_500k.zip')
lat_long_df=pd.read_excel('long_lat.xlsx')

ky_counties['fips'] = ky_counties['GEOID']
lat_long_df['fips'] = lat_long_df['fips'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
ky_counties = (ky_counties.merge(lat_long_df, how = 'left', on = 'fips'))


df=pd.read_excel('plot_data.xlsx')
df['fips'] = df['FIPS'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)

df_map = (ky_counties.merge(df, how = 'left', on = 'fips')
                     .rename(columns = {'incidence' : 'Incidence Rate',
                                       'hcp_cnt' : '# of HCPs',
                                       'NAME' : 'County Name',
                                       'STATE_NAME':'State'}))

new_df_map= df_map.copy()
df_map['# of HCPs'] = df_map['# of HCPs'].fillna('-')

import matplotlib
def colors2cmap(*args, name=None):
    cmap_data = [matplotlib.colors.to_hex(c) for c in args]
    cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name, cmap_data)
    return cmap
color_list=colors2cmap("#e1f2f2", "#A8DCDC", "#115F5F", name='color_list')
country_geo = os.path.join('us-states.json')
from branca import colormap as cm

m = folium.Map(location=[40, -96], zoom_start=4) #zoom_start = 5, max_zoom = 5
m.choropleth(
 geo_data=country_geo,
 name='choropleth',
 data=df_map,
 columns=['State', 'Incidence Rate'],
 key_on='feature.properties.name',
 fill_color='YlGn',
 fill_opacity=0.6, #.7
 line_opacity=0.1, #.2
 legend_name='Test'
)
plot_ll=new_df_map.groupby(by=['STUSPS','State'], as_index=False)['# of HCPs'].sum()
plot_ll['# of HCPs']=plot_ll['# of HCPs'].astype(int)
plot_ll=plot_ll[plot_ll['# of HCPs']>=1]

st_lat_lng=pd.read_csv('statelatlong.csv')
plot_ll=plot_ll.merge(st_lat_lng,how = 'inner', left_on='STUSPS', right_on='State')
# plot_ll=new_df_map.groupby(by=['STUSPS','State','lat','lng'], as_index=False)['# of HCPs'].sum()

locations=list(zip(plot_ll.lat, plot_ll.lng))
hcp_cnt_disp=list(plot_ll['# of HCPs'])
state_name=list(plot_ll['City'])

linear = cm.LinearColormap(["yellow", "yellow"], vmin=plot_ll['# of HCPs'].min(), vmax=plot_ll['# of HCPs'].max())

for i in range(len(locations)):
    folium.Marker(locations[i], icon=DivIcon(
            # icon_size=(150,36),
            icon_anchor=(5,7),
            html='<div style="font-size: 7pt; color : black; text-align: center">%s</div>'%hcp_cnt_disp[i],
            )).add_to(m)
    # m.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(p2, radius=15))

    m.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=locations[i],radius=8,fill=True, color = linear(hcp_cnt_disp[i]),
            opacity=0.4, fill_opacity=.3,
            tooltip='{}: {}'.format(",County Name: <b>"+state_name[i]+"</b><br>", "HCP Count: <b>"+str(hcp_cnt_disp[i])+"</b>")))
folium.TileLayer("CartoDB positron", show=False).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m.save('new_base_map.html')
```

Please help. TIA!

Comment: Unfortunately, `zoom_start` only accepts `int`egers so you can't strike a balance with 4.5 or something. Why not use `zoom_start=4` and increase the fontsizes?